# Automated Business Cards with Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am using a combination of Google Sheets, Google Presentation, and Zapier to automate my companies business card design workflow. My template looks like this:

```
{Full Name}}
{{Job Title}}

{{School Site}}
{{Street Address}}
Broken Arrow, Oklahoma {{Zip Code}}
{{Office Number}}{{Print Cell/Fax}}
{{Email}}
```

{{Print Cell/Fax}} is populated by a javascript step in Zapier that detects whether the submitter included their cell and fax numbers(These are optional)
and outputs a single variable. This script looks like this:

```
var cell = inputData.cell
var fax = inputData.fax
var cellFax

if (cell) {
  console.log('C: ', cell);
  cell='C: '+ inputData.cell;
}else{
  console.log('empty');
  cell=null;
}

if (fax) {
  console.log('F: ', fax);
  fax='F: '+ inputData.fax;
}else{
  console.log('empty');
  fax=null;
}

if (cell!=null && fax!=null) {
  cellFax=' / '+cell+fax;
}else if(cell!=null && fax==null) {
  cellFax=' / '+cell;
}else if(cell==null && fax!=null) {
  cellFax=' / '+fax;
}else{
  cellFax=null;
}

output = {cellFax: cellFax};
```

In the event that both cell and fax variables are empty I need it to populate my template place holder as empty like this:

John Doe
Janitor

International Space Station
555 S. Milkyway St.
Saturn, Vermont 11122
555-259-5555
email@email.com

But what I keep getting this:

John Doe
Janitor

International Space Station
555 S. Milkyway St.
Saturn, Vermont 11122
555-259-5555{{Print Cell/Fax}}
email@email.com

How Do I get it to populate as empty?

Answer (score 0):

try just changing this last part of the javascript from:

```
}else{
  cellFax=null;
}
```

to:

```
}else{
  cellFax=' ';
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. It still just populates as {{Print Cell/Fax}}

Comment: if you capture a cell or fax number, it outputs the expected result?

Comment: Yes, I even tried changing the last else statement to 
}else{
  cellFax='test';
} 

and that worked. When it is null, '' or ' ' it comes back as {{Print Cell/Fax}}.